# Ubuntu VM CPU overload

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04, cpu-usage

I'm having an Ubuntu 14.04 VM in a cloud environment and after I run a set of Apache Bench tests on a tomcat service I have this problem that I cant stop:

[image: htop results]

I tried to kill this process but it starts automatically after I'm killing it, eating all my CPU. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a Java VM environment for running things like an ERP System. It tends to use whatever resources are available in order to optimize and index portions of the database the application is linking to.

If this is a work-related PC or server I would advise you be very careful about playing around with this process until you figure out what application is running inside of Tomcat. It could be something mission critical to your business.